# How can I convert a Request object into a stringifiable object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, request, stringify

Using `Object` methods like `entries` and `keys` produce empty arrays. `JSON.stringify` yields an empty object in the browser and a circular reference error in Node.js.

```js
const request = new Request(
  'https://example.com/send',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'Hello world',
    headers: {'x-planet-origin': 'Mars'},
  },
);

const keys = Object.keys(request);
const values = Object.values(request);
const entries = Object.entries(request);
const string = JSON.stringify(request);

console.log({keys, values, entries, string, request});
```

Comment: why using `new Request` instead of `fetch` or any other way?

Comment: Since it's created from a constructor and not a plain object, it can't be stringified in a way that it'll be parseable back into a request object later, unless you do so explicitly on both sides, is that OK?

Comment: because I don't want to fetch the resource @brk

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I am aware of how the value types are being transformed during construction.

Comment: Big chance, those properties of the `requests` object are `non-enumberable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these functions to convert the stringifiable values in a Request object to values in a plain object. The first function alone will produce the described object, and the others will assist in producing a version with sorted properties.

```js
function requestAsObject (request) {
  if (!request instanceof Request)
    throw Object.assign(
      new Error(),
      {name: 'TypeError', message: 'Argument must be a Request object'}
    );
  request = request.clone();

  function stringifiableObject (obj) {
    const filtered = {};
    for (const key in obj)
      if (['boolean', 'number', 'string'].includes(typeof obj[key]) || obj[key] === null)
        filtered[key] = obj[key];
    return filtered;
  }

  return {
    ...stringifiableObject(request),
    headers: Object.fromEntries(request.headers),
    signal: stringifiableObject(request.signal),
    // bodyText: await request.text(), // requires function to be async
  };
}

function requestAsArrayEntries (request) {
  if (!request instanceof Request)
    throw Object.assign(
      new Error(),
      {name: 'TypeError', message: 'Argument must be a Request object'}
    );
  request = request.clone();

  function entriesFromObject (obj) {
    const entries = [];
    for (const key in obj)
      if (['boolean', 'number', 'string'].includes(typeof obj[key]) || obj[key] === null)
        entries.push([key, obj[key]]);
    return entries.sort();
  }

  return [
    ...entriesFromObject(request),
    ['headers', [...request.headers].sort()],
    ['signal', entriesFromObject(request.signal)],
    // ['bodyText', await request.text()], // requires function to be async
  ].sort();
}

function objectFromNestedEntries (arrayOfEntries) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arrayOfEntries)) return arrayOfEntries;
  const obj = {};
  for (const [key, value] of arrayOfEntries) {
    obj[key] = objectFromNestedEntries(value);
  }
  return obj;
}

const request = new Request('https://example.com/send', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: 'Hello world',
  headers: {'x-planet-origin': 'Mars'},
});

const object = requestAsObject(request);
const arrayEntries = requestAsArrayEntries(request);
const sortedObject = objectFromNestedEntries(arrayEntries);

console.log({
  object,
  arrayEntries,
  sortedObject,
  objectAsString: JSON.stringify(object),
  sortedObjectAsString: JSON.stringify(sortedObject),
});
```

Thanks, [Emeeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6121568/emeeus), for [helping me think in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57448069/438273).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
const request = new Request(
  'https://example.com/send',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'Hello world',
    headers: {'x-planet-origin': 'Mars'},
  },
);

const str = JSON.stringify(request, ['bodyUsed',
'cache',
'credentials',
'destination','headers',
'integrity',
'isHistoryNavigation',
'keepalive',
'method',
'mode',
'redirect',
'referrer',
'referrerPolicy',
'signal',
'url']);
 
console.log(str);

//iterating dinamically
let props = [];
for(let prop in request){
props.push(prop);
}

const str2 = JSON.stringify(request, props);
 
console.log(str2);
```

As you could see, properties like `signal` result on an empty object, if you don't need that kind of properties this is a possible solution.

If you still want properties like `signal` you could do something like this as a second step:

```
const signal = JSON.stringify(request.signal, ['aborted', 'onabort']);
```

Comment: Thank you for offering a suggestion. I would like to avoid manually specifying property values, in favor of an iterative or programmatic solution.

Comment: @jsejcksn As I added in the code, `for in` is a possible way to iterate over properties

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find a way to merge two requests together and I found that only `for in` loops work for Request objects.

```js
const request = new Request(
  'https://example.com/send',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'Hello world',
    headers: {'x-planet-origin': 'Mars'},
  },
);

function getEntries(req) {
  const out = {}
  for (const key in req) { out[key] = req[key] }
  return out
}

const entries = getEntries(request);
const string = JSON.stringify(entries);

console.log({entries, string, request});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `const reqrCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request))`

Then you can do all the methods you tried later on with `keys` and `entries` etc (on the copy). The request opject may be nested and therefore you want to do this to make a deep copy for those methods.

Comment: Have you tested this? Please provide your results using the example request object in my question.